# Put a default time on X-axis?

Tags: vb.net, date, charts, mschart

I have several series in one chart and I want the X-axis to show every day at 00:00 in the night as shown in the first picture below.

But when I add one series that is getting its date from a database, it changes to another time or format that I don't want (See picture 2).

This is the code that I'm using.

```
Dim theDate As Date
rows = dv.Table.Rows.Count
For i As Integer = 0 To rows - 1

    Debug.WriteLine(dv(i)(0))
    theDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dv(i)(0), "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss.f", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    Debug.WriteLine(theDate)

    'MsgBox(theDate.ToString("dd-MMM HH:MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))

    With chrCurrent
        .ChartAreas("chr" + type).AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = DateTimeIntervalType.Days
        .ChartAreas("chr" + type).AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd-MMM HH:mm"
        .Series("ser" + type).Points.AddXY(theDate, dv(i)(1))

    End With
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To 7 'Past 7 days
    With chrCurrent
        .Series("serHighHighLimit").Points.AddXY((DateSerial(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day - i)), (limitRedHigh))
Next
```

---

**PICTURE 1:**

> [image]

**PICTURE 2:**

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to set your X axis minimum value. You probably want to set it to the minimum date of your time series stripped of the hours, minutes and seconds

```
 .ChartAreas("chr" + type).AxisX.Minimum = #2/27/2014 00:00:0#
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks.